# Any idea to import data into PloneFormGen?

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

PloneFormGen does very good job to export saved data into .csv file. Can we import data from a .csv file into PloneFormGen?

Answer (score 0):

There's no feature for that, because PFG is designed as a system to collect information from users via forms.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your save data adapter, click the edit tab; choose the "saved data" subform. Paste in CSV. Save.

Your CSV will need to have the same dialect as PFG.